# Usage of "beschließen" and "vorhaben"

Tags: word-usage, difference, meaning

What is the difference between *vorhaben* and *beschließen*?

> 1. Im Dezember ***habe ich vor***, nach Deutschland zu fliegen, um meine Freundin zu besuchen.
> 2. Im Dezember ***beschließe ich***, nach Deutschland zu fliegen, um meine Freundin zu besuchen.

Comment: Wenn Du heute sagst, dass Du im Dezember beschließen oder vorhaben wirst ... dann hast Du es doch längst beschlossen oder vor. Gut - jetzt ist heute ein Tag des Dezembers, aber wenn die Entscheidung gefallen ist, muss es "beschloss ich" heißen. Man könnte sagen "Im Januar habe ich vor zu joggen" und meinen "Für Januar habe ich vor zu joggen", d.h. das Vorhaben hättest Du schon heute, aber das Joggen soll im Januar stattfinden. P.S.: Die Freundin tut zur Frage nichts bei - oder? Ich würde die Beispiele doch auf das Wesentliche beschränken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just answer with the translations for now, as writing a long answer on the mobile client is difficult.

Your first sentence translates to:

> I plan to fly to Germany in December to visit my SO.

The second sentence means something very different:

> In December I decide to fly to Germany to visit my SO.

To put it in extremely short:
Etwas vorhaben = to plan something
Etwas beschließen = to decide (on) something

Comment: I thought they both mean to decide. Thanks

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Yes depending on context they can, but i am not able to condense this enough so that i will not kill mys3lf writing that on mobile client..

Comment: I don't think "vorhaben" ever means to decide. If so then even buying means to decide because there was a decision made.

Comment: @Emanuel man kann so ziemlich jedes *"ich habe vor"* durch ein *"ich habe beschlossen"* ersetzen...

Comment: Ja, aber ich kann auch jedes "Ich habe diese Suppe gekauft" durch ein "Ich habe mich für diese Suppe entschieden" ersetzen. Vieles, was wir im Präsens machen basiert auf Entscheidungen. Frei kann ich vieles in vieles übersetzen. Aber deshalb ist "to decide" trotzdem KEINE Übersetzung von "vorhaben" das es eben NUR perfektiv funktioniert. EIne Übersetzung sollte aber in jeder Zeit funktionieren.