# Können Verben Bezug auf eine Infinitivgruppe nehmen? Komma fakultativ oder obligatorisch?

Tags: comma, infinitive

In der Frage [Usage of "beschließen" and "vorhaben"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8812/usage-of-beschlie%C3%9Fen-and-vorhaben) schreibt der OP folgenden Beispielsatz:

> Im Dezember habe ich vor, nach Deutschland zu fliegen, um meine Freundin zu besuchen.

Im ersten Moment war ich davon überzeugt, dass das erste Komma fakultativ ist. Grund:

> Infinitivgruppen, Partizipgruppen, Adjektivgruppen und entsprechende Wortgruppen **können** durch Kommas abgetrennt werden, um die Gliederung des Ganzsatzes zu verdeutlichen (§ 75 E2) oder sie als Zusatz oder Nachtrag zu kennzeichnen (§ 75 E2 u. § 78.3).

Infinitivgruppen müssen jedoch mit einem Komma abgetrennt werden, ...

> ... wenn sie durch ein Wort oder eine Wortgruppe angekündigt oder wieder aufgenommen werden

Mir ist hier nicht klar, ob *vorhaben* hier in diese Rolle schlüpft, da es den Bezug auf die Infinitivgruppe darstellt. Muss die Infinitivgruppe nun durch ein Komma abgetrennt werden oder gilt hier die allgemeine Regel und das Komma ist folglich optional?
Kann ein Verb überhaupt als "Ankündigung" fungieren? Ich finde nämlich keinen Hinweis dazu, weder im Regelwerk noch in anderen verlässlichen Quellen.

---

Die Definitionen sind dem canoo.net Artikel zu [Das Komma bei Infinitivgruppen (zu + Infinitiv), Partizipgruppen und Adjektivgruppen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/PartAdjInf.html?lang=en) entnommen.

---

Das zweite Komma ist übrigens definitiv obligatorisch, da Infinitivgruppen, die mit *um*, *ohne*, *statt*, *anstatt*, *außer* und *als* eingeleitet werden, mit Komma abgegrenzt werden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In den offiziellen Regeln werden Infinitive nicht danach unterschieden, ob sie »angekündigt« sind, sondern von was für einem Wort sie abhängen – und nur im seltenen Fall, dass ein Infinitiv Subjekt des Satzes ist, hängt er nicht von einem anderen Wort ab. Hängt nun ein (erweiterter) Infinitiv von einem Substantiv, Verweiswort, Korrelat oder *um, ohne, statt* usw. ab, ist das Komma obligatorisch (§ 75). In allen anderen Fällen, d. h. z. B. bei Abhängigkeit von einem Verb, Adjektiv oder Adverb ist das Komma optional (§ 75, E2). Verben werden nicht explizit erwäht, da das obligatorische Komma die Ausnahme ist, und eben nur auf die Ausnahme- und nicht auf die Normalfälle eingegangen wird.

Oder mit anderen Worten: Verben können nicht hinweisen.

Zu § 78 (3) gibt es noch folgendes Beispiel, das dem Satz aus der Frage nicht unähnlich ist:

> Er beabsichtigte(,) nach seiner Ausbildung ein Studium aufzunehmen.

Answer (score 1):

Wie sich aus der Diskussion mit @Wrzlprmft ergab, hat die Zusammenfassung, auf welche ich mich bei der Frage bezogen habe, eine zu starke Globalisierung des Regelwerks ausgeübt.

Während im Regelwerk von "Korrelat oder Verweiswort" (=Platzhalter) die Rede ist, so wird in der Zusammenfassung von "hinweisendes Wort" bzw. von "ankündigen und wieder aufnehmen" geredet.

Diese Umformulierung brachte mich aufs Glatteis, da diese so allgemein gehalten ist, dass es für mich nahe lag, ein Verb ebenfalls zu der Gruppe zuzuordnen.

Im Endeffekt sind Verben aber vollkommen unerheblich für die Entscheidung, ob ein Komma gesetzt werden muss oder nicht. Da im Beispielssatz kein Korrelat vorliegt, so ist das Komma fakultativ.

> Im Dezember habe ich vor(,) nach Deutschland zu fliegen, um meine Freundin zu besuchen.